# How to get COMplusExceptionCode from a standard Exception

Tags: com

How do I get the COMplusExceptionCode from a standard Exception that doesn't already have it in the GetMessage? Thank you very much.

```
try
{
  ...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  // How do I get the COMplusExceptionCode from ex?

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm aware that this was asked a long time ago, but for anyone still looking for an answer to this, there are a number of ways of finding the COMException code if Visual Studio hasn't generated a .NET `Exception` object for you.

You first need to add a break point into your COMException catch statement to catch the exception. Then do one of the following:

1. The easiest method is to use the debugging controls to step into the `catch` statement, where Visual Studio should display a warning icon underneath the exception... click on this to view the related .NET exception. If Visual Studio has not generated a related exception, keep reading.
2. Use Intellisense - put your mouse cursor over the name of the exception in the `catch` declaration and drill all the way down to the `Non-Public members` section.
3. Use the Quick Watch Window to view the exception object and drill down to the `Non-Public members` section as above.
4. Type System.Exception._COMPlusExceptionCode into the Immediate Window.

All you will see for methods 2-4 however, is a single code number that you will then have to search the internet to find a meaning for.